# In laravel how can i start all my queue using single artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I have a large number of users hence I have to do that particular user has their queue not just one queue for all users. `php artisan queue:work` this command runs only default named queue. but in my case queue name is according to the user for example "user_1"; this is the first user queue name
I tried this `php artisan queue:work --queue=*` but this did not work for me. I also tried `dispatchNow` method but this method is deprecated. so I'm expecting a solution in just one command to run all queues that are stored in the database with a unique name.
Also, note that this task needs to be performed in background

Answer (score 0):

Take the following approach:

```
$queueName = 'user_1';

$command = "php artisan queue:work --queue=$queueName";

$output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
```

Comment: will this run in the background process?

Comment: All queue's run in the background process.

Comment: actually, I'm asking about your provided code.